# Show that a certain set is a continuity set of a certain measure

Tags: measure-theory

Let $\nu$ be a measure defined on borelians of $\mathbb R^n$ and let $\mathcal C_\nu$ be the class of
continuity sets of $\nu$ (i.e. the class of sets $E$ such that $\nu (\partial E)=0$, where $\partial E$ is the boundary of $E$). Given $V= B(0,\epsilon)$, with $\epsilon >0$, a neighborhood of $0$. Suppose that $V \in \mathcal C_\nu$. Define:
$$\mu(A):= \nu(A \cap V^c), \quad \forall \, A \,\, \hbox{ borelian of } \mathbb R^n$$
So, I want to show that if $A \in \mathcal C_\mu$, i.e., $\mu (\partial A)= \nu(\partial A \cap V^c) =0$, then $E:= A \cap V^c$ is a continuity set of $\nu$, i.e.:
$$\nu (\partial E)= \nu( \partial (A \cap V^c)  ) =0$$

My attempt is try to use
$$\partial (A\cap V^c) \subset \partial (A) \cup \partial (V^c) $$
On the one hand, I have $\nu (\partial V^c)=0$, but I don't necessarily have $\nu(\partial A)=0$.

I don't know if there is another faster and simpler way to show this or if there is simply a counterexample.